# using bootstrap4 modal in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to render a modal with a simple change in my data using a vue @click on an element but I'm not able to get the modal to popup. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

I'm not using vue-bootstrap in this project just bootstrap 4 for reference here.

my click

```
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
       <span class="d-block">These students cannot be in the same group:</span>
       <button @click="showModal = true" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Add constraint group</button>
  </div>
```

my Modal

```
<!--MODAL SECTION-->
        <div v-if="showModal" class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                         <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<!--MODAL SECTION-->
```

my data

```
data:{
otherData: [],
showModal: false
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify how it is showing now?

Comment: currently it isn't showing at all. I am trying to use an @click to change the showModal prop in data to 'true' but that doesn't seem to be the right way of doing it.

Comment: Have you chceck `$('#myModal').modal('show')` is working?

Comment: @Rjosh yes I was able to get it to work eventually by using this after making sure js popper was included properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need data-toggle and data-target on the button:

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <span class="d-block">These students cannot be in the same group:</span>
    <button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" @click="showModal = true" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Add constraint group</button>
</div>
```

See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-data-attributes

Since the modal is controlled via some bootstrap internals, I do not think you need the `v-if` and `@click` handler.

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work using either the v-if or the data-target method unfortunately. I have also tried using v-model to no effect. I know bootstrap is included. Does js popper need to be included to use bootstrap modals?

Comment: after including js popper the modal now works for some reason. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @monsterpiece awesome! What version of bootstrap 4 are you using? Popper was required for modals in the beta versions, but I do not think it is required in the current version (4.4.1). Some CDNs serve older versions.

Comment: I was using 4.4.1 I might be mistaken and I made a fluke change by accident but that seemed to be the fix for me.